# php mysql display name once instead of the number of times it has been entered

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query but it returns the name of author the number of times it exists in the database ..

> $query = "SELECT bauthor FROM info WHERE Cat1 = 'novel'";
>   $result = MySQL_query($query);

i want the author's name to be displayed once and the number of books he has to be in a bracket ...for example author's name is aaaaa and he has written 20 books so wen i run this query it shows mw his name 20 times but i want it to be in this way aaaa(20)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't do much without your full schema, but try using the `COUNT` feature with a `GROUP BY` clause, like

```
SELECT bauthor, COUNT(books) AS numbooks FROM info WHERE ... GROUP BY bauthor
```

EDIT: See this SQLFiddle for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb5f5/1/0

Comment: WHy `COUNT(books)` and not `COUNT(*)`?  Do you have reason to believe that `books` might be `NULL` in some records (and that such records should be excluded from the count)?

Comment: @eggyal Because since the author's name is a string rather than a FK and lookup table, there could be other gotchas in this database design, like, say the schema is (author, book_title, publish_country), or even (author, book_title, category), where a book can belong to multiple categories. Plus, `*` is evil. I wanted to count the number of books, so I used `COUNT(books)`.

Comment: `SELECT *` is evil;  `COUNT(*)` is recommended.

Comment: @eggyal - then again, to guard against other stupidities in the table design.

Comment: @eggyal, also, do you have reason to believe `books` might _not_ be `NULL`?

Comment: I don't follow.  Whereas the `*` in `SELECT *` means "all columns", the `*` in `COUNT(*)` has a completely different meaning of "count the number of records, irrespective of their content".  If anything, it guards against stupidities better than naming a column.

Comment: @eggyal - in my slightly contrived case, my code was wrong, and should have been `COUNT(DISTINCT books)`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd66c/3/0 to see what I was trying to get at.

Comment: Okidoke.  For `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I keep forgetting the distinction between `COUNT(x)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`

Comment: Thank you :) ...it worked .. All is ok ..but how can it get it to be displayed this way .... authorname(19)

Comment: Format it in PHP. If you really want, you could `SELECT CONCAT(authorname, '(', COUNT(DISTINCT books), ')')`, but that's nasty at the best of times.